# AFNetworking 3.0 migration for redirect block

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

How can I update this deprecated function to use AFNetworking 3.0?

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation=[[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_URLString]]];
    [requestOperation setRedirectResponseBlock:^NSURLRequest *(NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLRequest *request, NSURLResponse *redirectResponse) {
        if (redirectResponse) {
            //this is the redirected url
            NSLog(@"%@",request.URL);
        }
        return request;
    }];
    [requestOperation start];
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `setTaskWillPerformHTTPRedirectionBlock` on `AFHTTPSessionManager`.  The block set will be called if the initial URL request redirects.  You have the option to follow the redirect, or stop the redirect in the block.

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
[manager setTaskWillPerformHTTPRedirectionBlock:^NSURLRequest * _Nonnull(NSURLSession * _Nonnull session, NSURLSessionTask * _Nonnull task, NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, NSURLRequest * _Nonnull request) {
    NSLog(@"%@", request.URL);
    // This will be called if the URL redirects
    return request; // return request to follow the redirect, or return nil to stop the redirect
}];
[manager GET:_URLString parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

I would recommend you read through the [AFNetworking 3.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-3.0-Migration-Guide).

Comment: AFNetworking 3.1.0 doesn't seem to support a nil return for the redirection Block, so it expects a valid URLRequest. What is the best way to intercept the redirect and prevent it from not performing it's redirection?

Comment: @Bocaxica Did you found out what is the best way to intercept the redirect and prevent it from not performing it's redirection while using AFNetworking 3.x

Comment: @SSuman99 Yes, rather than `return nil` I just return a `URLRequest` to an `Associated Domain` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/setting_up_an_app_s_associated_domains).

Answer (score 1):

In some case you need to set the header for the request, just set `requestSerializer` using `requestSerializer setValue: forHTTPHeaderField:` as bellow :

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[manager setTaskWillPerformHTTPRedirectionBlock:^NSURLRequest * _Nonnull(NSURLSession * _Nonnull session, NSURLSessionTask * _Nonnull task, NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, NSURLRequest * _Nonnull request) {
    NSLog(@"%@", request.URL);
    // This will be called if the URL redirects
    return request; // return request to follow the redirect, or return nil to stop the redirect
}];
[manager GET:_URLString parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```